# handleResize using break points and throttling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider a component that tracks the window's width and returns `1` or `0` based on a given point:

```
export function useWindowResize() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth < 650 ? 1 : 0)
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => setWidth((window.innerWidth < 650 ? 1 : 0))
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    }
  }, )
  return width
}
```

If we place the condition at the places shown in the example above a re-render will occur only at the given break point.
But if we place the condition in the return a re-render will occur on each resize:

```
export function useWindowResize() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => setWidth((window.innerWidth))
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    }
  }, )
  return width < 650 ? 1 : 0
}
```

If I understand correctly in the first example each window resize triggers the condition check and sets the state, then the hook compares the states and since the true/false doesn't change until the break point the component doesn't re-render.

My questions are:
A. Which way is more resource efficient?
B. Should I still throttle the event listener on the first example?